# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml on line 37

Tags: parsing, magento, syntax

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml on line 37:

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
```

How to modify it.Thanks in advance.
Just it was showed on home page.

**original:**

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135) ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_product->getName(),60,'鈥?)); ?></a></h3>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
    <div ><img src="http://www.onlyforcars.com/images/freeshipping.jpg" width="97" height="14" alt="Free Shipping" /></div>
            <div class="actions">
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($_compareUrl = $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: So sorry,I have made a wrong detail before.just now i have modify it.line 37 is showing "<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>".

Comment: Sorry, but your "example website" leads everybody to flag your question as spam. Advertisment is not very much liked. If you really don't know how to solve your problem, you should reform youe question from a neutral programmers point of view. Thanks

Comment: In fact,I just want to provide more details to check more clearly.Sorry for my unprofessional view.

Comment: In name of community, thanks for rearranging your question. I couldn't reproduce your error while clicking on your example, btw. And in your next edit you should take of SOS, I forgot to mention it. No one here is an emergency.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly mention. sorry,I am a new comer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the third param of your `Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate()` call, where the ending string delimiter seems to be missing.

You get the `unexpected T_STRING` error, because the interpreter reaches the next string (`'short'`), while knowing that the previous string end wasn't found yet.

Replace this line

```
<h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_product->getName(),60,'鈥?)); ?></a></h3>
```

with this line

```
<h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_product->getName(),60,'鈥?')); ?></a></h3>
```

Comment: and how to do it now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the missing single quote at the end of the 3rd param of your `truncate` call.

Comment: Sorry,I am new comer.Could you list it fully here thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated my answer. No offense, but I'd recommend to get at least some basic programming skills. If adding a single quote at a specific position in your code is a problem, you're definitely not ready to work on complex stuff like Magento yet, imo.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It works.I am learning it now.Thanks for your recommend.